# Cloudwatch Insights query to return the find first AND last results only

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have a query that returns a number of results that show the start and end of transactions in the logs. So for every transaction there's a "start" and an "end" log entry.

```
fields @timestamp, @message 
| parse @message "*: *" as logContext, logMessage
| filter (logContext like "Transaction start"
       or logContext like "Transaction end")
| sort @timestamp asc
```

An example log might look like this:

```
Transaction start: Message 1 received
Transaction processing: Message 1 identified as "GetData"
Transaction processing: Message 1 "GetData" extracting fields
Transaction processing: Message 1 "GetData" routing - none
Transaction end: Message 1 commit
...
...
Transaction start: Message 49085 received
Transaction processing: Message 49085 identified as "DataResponse"
Transaction processing: Message 49085 "DataResponse" extracting fields
Transaction processing: Message 49085 "DataResponse" routing - return to sender
Transaction end: Message 2 commit
```

I want to only return the start of the first and end of the last transactions in the logs so that I can measure the time between them based on @timestamp.

```
2021-06-14T15:25:00, Transaction start: Message 1 received
2021-06-15T09:45:00, Transaction end: Message 49085 commit
```

I know I can use `limit` to return the first OR last depending on sort order, but not sure how to return both.

Comment: Can you give us an example of the real logs?

Comment: Good call @jellycsc. Updated question with example log and desired output.

Comment: Does anyone know how to get cloudwatch to return just the earliest timestamp?

Steve

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `stats` command, along with the `earliest` and `latest` functions, like this:

```
stats
  earliest(@timestamp) as firstTimestamp,
  latest(@timestamp) as lastTimestamp,
  lastTimestamp - firstTimestamp as durationMs
```

So, for the specific query used in the question, you could do this:

```
fields @timestamp, @message 
| parse @message "*: *" as logContext, logMessage
| filter (logContext like "Transaction start"
       or logContext like "Transaction end")
| stats
    earliest(@timestamp) as firstTimestamp,
    latest(@timestamp) as lastTimestamp,
    lastTimestamp - firstTimestamp as durationMs
```

Comment: Hello ! Where can I find the documents with all or most of the syntax like these, to query out the required fields?

Comment: Also, how can I learn more about parsing message? I am still not able to figure that out